# How to reload the bootstrap modal (not the whole page)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My modal gets the datas from a BD, but the problem is that when the client modify the datas and close, when it open again, the modal shows the datas modified by the client.
This happens because the modal just get the datas when the page is loaded. I want the modal to get the datas every time the client click to show the modal. Like reload the modal.
How could I do that?

Comment: Hi Julia! Welcome to the Stackoverflow community! Could you please take a look at the link below, then you can improve your question with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you e_e
 I'm going to read right now :D

Answer (score 2):

Two ways of doing this first are with the page reload that we want to avoid, and the second is with ajax. 
For example, you have a modal with a simple form on it with a list of user names (for displaying), input field, submit and cancel buttons.

Let say that input field is userName. So when client opens a modal, ajax request is sent. You wait for response and render it in the modal as a list.

User enters a new userName and submits form. Modal closes. If you open modal again, you send another request, on success you first destroy old list, you render new with ajax response and you are ready. Here is some rough example:

**Modal** - something like ...

```
<div id="userName" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">User names</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <ul id="result">
        <li>userName1</li>
        <li>userName2</li>
        <li>userName3</li>
      </ul>
        <p>input field goes here.</p>
        <form id="userNameForm" action="https://farfaraway/process" method="POST">
          <input class="form-group" type="text" name="userName">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" form="userNameForm" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="openModal">Inser username</button>
```

**JQuery** something like:

```
$('#openModal').on('click',function(){
    openUserNameModal();
});

function openUserNameModal() {
    var ueserName = $('userName').val();

  //ajax request
  $.ajax({
  url: "https://farfaraway/process", 
  method: "post",
  data:{"userName": userName},
  success: function(result){
    if(result){
      //destroy result list items with something like
      $('#result').html('');
      //render result embeded in html with something like
      $('#result').html( /*your html*/ );
      //open modal
        $('#userName').modal('show');
    }
  }});
}
```

Or if you just want to delete input field, you would use something like this

```
$('#openModal').on('click',function(){
    $('#userNameForm input').val('');
    $('#userName').modal('show');
});
```

This is of course rough example just to get you going. Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you very much, it's what I was looking for :D You helped me so much!